# Do Llama-2 and Code-Llama models collects my code?

Tags: llama-2, privacy

As you know, Open Ai states that data collected through chatgpt is used to improve their models, but by using the OpenAi’s api, this is not stored or collected: https://openai.com/security

I would like to know if llama-2 or code-llama do the same with the queries. I’m interested in using code-llama to do pair programming, but I don’t know if my code will be stored by Meta.

Comment: Can you please post "I also would like to know if the code thats generated by these AI models is licensed somehow or has copyright issues" as a separate question? Thanks

Comment: Thanks I've already created a separated question: https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/526/is-the-generated-code-by-code-llama-and-llama-2-models-licensed-somehow-or-it-ha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if llama-2 or code-llama do the same with the queries

No, those models run on your computer, unless of course if you are using some  llama-2 or code-llama  deployed on some server ([example](https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/teams/playground/models/codellama)).

> Open Ai states that data collected through chatgpt is used to improve their models,

OpenAI doesn't collect data from ChatGPT Enterprise.