# Is the generated code by Code-Llama and LLama-2 models licensed somehow or it has copyright issues?

Tags: llama-2, legal

I've been struggling with finding info about this on the official docs. I would like to use Code-Llama for pair programming but I don't know if this AI generated code is licensed somehow or I could just use it without worrying about copyright issues

Answer (score 3):

From https://github.com/facebookresearch/codellama:

> See the [LICENSE](https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama/blob/main/LICENSE) file, as well as our accompanying [Acceptable Use Policy](https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama/blob/main/USE_POLICY.md)

One can make a commercial use of Code Llama as long as one respects the license and the Acceptable Use Policy. Note these two restrictions from the license:

> v. You will not use the Llama Materials or any output or results of the
> Llama Materials to improve any other large language model (excluding Llama 2 or
> derivative works thereof).

and:

> 2. Additional Commercial Terms. If, on the Llama 2 version release date, the
>    monthly active users of the products or services made available by or for Licensee,
>    or Licensee's affiliates, is greater than 700 million monthly active users in the
>    preceding calendar month, you must request a license from Meta, which Meta may
>    grant to you in its sole discretion, and you are not authorized to exercise any of the
>    rights under this Agreement unless or until Meta otherwise expressly grants you
>    such rights.

Also, it [may](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38431/4) happen that Code-Llama plagiarizes some code from its training set. Unlikely, but not 100% sure it won't happen.

This is assuming one uses https://github.com/facebookresearch/codellama  and not a third-party provider, which may have other ToS.